# sObject Get Deleted endpoint permissions

Tags: rest-api, permissions

I'm new to salesforce and all it's intricacies. I inherited a code base and am having issues figuring out (what i believe to be) an environmental issue.

I'm receiving an `INVALID_OPERATION_WITH_EXPIRED_PASSWORD` when trying to grab the deleted contacts using the v42.0 version of the REST endpoints.

Looks like so: `https//<..environment-url.com>/services/data/v42.0/sobjects/Contact/deleted/?<query-string-stuff>`

The same user is able to access the bulk api and pull data without issue. I'm using the python simple-salesforce library, both operations are happening within the same session.

Additionally, accessing the delete endpoint works fine in another environment.

I feel like this is certainly a permissions issue, but from what I can see all permissions are the same.

Can anyone here point me to specific setup that could cause issues accessing the rest api?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried changing your password? What happens if you log in to the UI? Are you prompted to change your password?

Comment: From the login response, can you tell us what is returned in `passwordExpired` field? If this returns `true`, API calls will be restricted but login allowed.